# [Multisite]How can I update custom blog option?

Tags: admin, settings-api, options

I wanted to update custom blog option created thru Settings Api using the function `update_blog_option`. I created this code.

```
    $country_base = get_blog_option($blog_id, 'mytheme_options');//retrieve all options
    $country_base['country_base'] = $the_country;
    $currency_unit = get_blog_option($blog_id, 'mytheme_options');//retrieve all options
    $currency_unit['currency_unit'] = $d_currency;

    update_blog_option($blog_id, 'mytheme_options', $country_base);
    update_blog_option($blog_id, 'mytheme_options', $currency_unit);
```

However, its not working.. Is there way to update custom blog option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Codex on update_blog_option](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/update_blog_option):

> Switches to the blog id specified, runs update_option() and then
>   restores to the current blog. If $refresh is true then it will refresh
>   the blog details.

---

Not tested, but I think your problem is trying to update elements of the array instead of the whole thing:

```
$the_options = get_blog_option($blog_id, 'mytheme_options');//retrieve all options

$the_options['country_base'] = $the_country;
$the_options['currency_unit'] = $d_currency;

update_blog_option($blog_id, 'mytheme_options', $the_options);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best just to `switch_to_blog($id);` and use regular functions as add_option(), get_option(), update_option(). When you're done you'd better use `restore_current_blog();` to switch back.